# Set Property Value on Master Page from Content Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, roles

I need to pass data to a variable in my master page each time a page is loaded.

I have a string[] of RequiredRoles that I set on each content page defining what roles are required to access that page.

On my master page, I have a method that takes this array, and checks to see if the current user is in one or more of those roles.

How would I go about managing this? I basically want each page to have a String[] RequiredRoles defined, and the master page will load this on each call and check to see if the users are in those roles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a property in your master page and you access it from content page:

Master page:

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private string[] _RequiredRoles = null;

    public string[] RequiredRoles
    {
        get { return _RequiredRoles; }
        set { _RequiredRoles = value; }
    }
}
```

Content Page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        Master.RequiredRoles = new string[] { /*set appropriate roles*/ };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Add page directive to your child page:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Then add property to your master page:

```
public string Section { get; set; }
```

You can access this property like this:

```
Master.Section = "blog";
```

Comment: Voted this answer up over the others because it shows the use of the <%@ MasterType %> directive, which makes things work much better from content page - especially intellisense in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 15):

Typecast Page.Master to your master page so that you are doing something like:

```
((MyMasterPageType)Page.Master).Roles = "blah blah";
```

Comment: what is MyMasterPageType?

Comment: @Niloofar: When you create a master page, it creates a new class.  In my example you'd replace `MyMasterPageType` with the name of your actual master page class.

Answer (score 6):

I'd go by creating a base class for all the content pages, something like:

```
public abstract class BasePage : Page
{
    protected abstract string[] RequiredRoles { get; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // display the required roles in a master page
        if (this.Master != null) {
            // value-assignment
        }

    }
}
```

And then I make every page inherits from BasePage, and each defining a RequiredRoles

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
    protected override string[] RequiredRoles
    {
        get { return new[] { "Admin", "Moderator" }; }
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of cleanliness and DRY-ing the OnLoad handler code. And every page which inherits from BasePage are required to define a "RequiredRoles" or else it won't compile.

Comment: This one hasn't been upvoted enough.  It's the correct approach on handling the requirement even if it's different from exact issue the OP was trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

CType(Master.FindControl("lblName"), Label).Text = txtId.Text
  CType(Master.FindControl("pnlLoginned"), Panel).Visible = True