# Set Property Value on Master Page from Content Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, roles

I tried following the advice posted here:
[Set Property Value on Master Page from Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071920/set-property-value-on-master-page-from-content-page).

Specifically the last post about creating a class. However, visual studio keeps giving me an error on my default.aspx.cs page when i try to set the value:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Web;  
using System.Web.UI;  
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;  

public partial class _Default : BasePage  
{  

    protected override int NavHighlight  
    {  
        get { return new{0} ; }  
    }  

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  

    }  
}
```

It throws an error on `new`, the error being: `cannot inplicity convert anonymoustype#1 to int`

Can someone tell me what i might have done wrong here?

Here's what my class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for BasePage
/// </summary>
public abstract class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected abstract int NavHighlight { get; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (this.Master != null)
        { 
            //value assignment 
        }
    }

 public BasePage()
 {
  //
  // TODO: Add constructor logic here
  //
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you cast your master page as shown in your referenced question?

Comment: sorry - i missed that (and still am missing it). where is that being done in the example i linked to? Thanks for the help.

Comment: ((MyMasterPageType)Page.master).Roles = "blah blah";

Comment: Ah ok - last comment. Where would that be done in the code then? I dont really understand what that line of code is doing. Sorry for my newbishness.

Just to be clear - i'm trying to follow the example as given by chakrit on that page. 

thanks for the help

Comment: Hey don - any chance you can explain where that line of code you mentioned belongs? I dont really understand what it's doing or if it applies to the suggestion as posted by chakrit

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct code should be

```
protected override int NavHighlight  
{  
    get { return 0; }  
}
```

Not

```
protected override int NavHighlight  
{  
    get { return new{0}; }  
}
```

It has nothing to do at all with Master Page / Content Page.