# Pass Query string from aspx to master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass query string to masterpage from aspx page. But the specific aspx page doesn't use masterpage reference. I just need to pass a string value to master page.

```
string strUserID = Request.QueryString["Value"]
```

I am very new to asp.net. Please help me solve this.

Comment: A master page cannot be called without a page, its only purpose is to provide a template for a page. If your .aspx page doesn't use a master page you will not be able to send anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Access `HttpRequest` and it's properties inside of `yourMasterPage.Context`. For example: this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you please explain in brief?How can I pass this to my master page`string strUserID = Request.QueryString["Value"]`

Comment: What I am trying to say that inside of your master you can use same construct to get the values from query string. Like this: `yourMasterPage.Context.QueryString["Value"]`. The other option may be to add a property to your master page, and then set that property inside of your page.(like here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071920/set-property-value-on-master-page-from-content-page)